# Install MediaPipe in Virtual Env (VSCode) in Mac pro M1

Tags: python-3.x

I can't install MediaPipe in Mac M1 with `pip install mediapipe` or `conda install mediapipe` .
I was trying many solutions suggested in SO and others, but they didn't work so far.

Tried with Python ver 3.8 and 3.9
Virtual env: VSCode

Please help. Thanks & Regards!

Comment: Welcome to SO ;)
Please add the full stack trace error to question.

Answer (score 0):

Mediapipe isn't supporting the M1 **(arm64)** ATM.

You can find more information here:

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2798

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).